# WebStorm and Material 2 directives

Tags: angular, webstorm, angular-material2

I have an angular-cli project created with WebStorm with [Material 2 Components](https://github.com/angular/material2) and everything runs fine.

In WebStorm however i have an issue where some attribute directives are not found by the editor even though i'm importing everything correctly according to the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/). I'm getting this problem with the `matHeaderCellDef`, `matCellDef` and `matRowDef` in particular:

[image]

This is on a newly created project using the code of the basic table [described here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview). This happens on both the latest stable build and EAP (builds `172.3968.37` and `173.3727.2` respectively).

Another curious things I've noticed when trying to debug this issue: when importing anything from `@angular/material` in `app.module.ts`, i automatically get a lot of material directives on autocomplete even though they are on different modules. This does not seem to happen in the EAP build however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logged as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29827, please follow it for updatees